# German umlauts doesn't display in VS Code

Tags: visual-studio-code

I have some HTML files that contain German Umlaut like ö, ü. But in my VS Code, they are shown as �. I have tried to resolve the problem by installing the German language in the VS Code, in the Windows setting. But I am still facing the problem.

Code is shown in the notepad

```html
<title>App Bootsmanöver mit Aussenbordmotor</title>
```

Code is shown in the VS Code

```html
<title>App Bootsman�ver mit Aussenbordmotor</title>
```

Comment: Do you happen to have a non-default font configured for your editor?
Check **Editor: Font Family** setting in your Settings UI and try resetting it.

Comment: @DorinBotan nothing happens

Comment: Your file is probably stored under some weird encoding (utf-8 would the usual). In Notepad, you can see the (correct) encoding in the bottom right corner. Select the same encoding in vscode, There is a small button in the bottom right corner as well.

Comment: Yes. The problem was in file encoding, not in the language pack. **ANSI** encoding is used in these files.

Answer (score 1):

For clean ä,ö,ü save .html files as

"UTF-8 with BOM"

(only "UTF-8" does not work in VS code - there, use icon bottom right for file type) together with

Answer (score 0):

Solution for me was to apply the Western (Windows 1252) Encoding.